# How to store text based data in blazor maui application

Tags: blazor, maui, text-based

I am new to programming. I am developing a blazor Maui app to run on both android and ios platforms. This application displays text for each of the links in the home page. There are around 40 different links in the home page and each link will have sub links again depending on the option. I could add the text into the page directly. But I would like to know if there are other options where I can store all the data and the page gets automatically refreshed when I add the data to the database?

Thanks in advance.

I tried adding the text to the page component.

Comment: Either store it in a file or a database, and then build the UI dynamically based on that data.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of storage location, it is generally divided into long-term storage and short-term storage.

For long-term storage, there are `file` and `database`, as well as some Azure services, such as: `Azure Storage`, `Azure DB`. For temporary storage, there are `Session`, `cookie`, `cache`.

Depending on your specific needs, it is recommended that you use `database` to implement it.

Since your description says that link has sub link, you can create a `parent-child-tree` table in the database to store the data. The database columns have the following fields: `Id`, `text`, `link url`, `parent id`,etc. Then you can use SQL code to do things like insert, delete, update, and query, and then render it to the UI.

For more information, please check: [How to Query a Parent-Child Tree in SQL](https://learnsql.com/blog/query-parent-child-tree/) and [Hierarchical Data Management](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/255/entity-framework-recipe-hierarchical-data-management).